# mockito checking MethodInvocation

Tags: java, proxy, mockito, interceptor

I would like to check that method was invoked with particular parameter using mockito.

I my code, everytime when `unit.permission().someCommand()` is invoked, the intercetor's method `invoke` will be invoked along with that. `invoke` method looks like this:

```
void invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) ..
```

This is a test, where I check that interceptor's method was invoked.

```
@Test
public void permission() throws Throwable {
    unit.permission().someCommand();

    verify(mockedMethodInterceptor, times(1)).invoke(any(MethodInvocation.class));
}
```

In this test, as you can see, I use any instance of MethodInvocation.

Question:

Is there any way to check to particular MethodInvocation instance to be sure that invoke() method was invoked with right parameter? This invoke method should hold information about someCommand() method..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For this simple case, it's probably ok just to use the value itself in the test:

```
@Test
public void permission() throws Throwable {
    MethodInvocation expectedInvocation = makeItHoweverYouDo();
    unit.permission().someCommand();

    verify(mockedMethodInterceptor, times(1)).invoke(expectedInvocation);
}
```

Getting that to *be* the one that's actually called by your code may require that you inject that value somewhere in your production code.  You might need changes to even make that possible.

If you have any use of `Matcher`s in your `verify` call, you have to use them everywhere.  For that purpose, there's a matcher (`eq`) for matching a value:

```
    verify(mockedMethodInterceptor, times(1)).invoke(eq(expectedInvocation));
```

You don't need it here, but if your method had another argument where you wanted to use an `any` matcher, you'd need it.

Comment: Two things to note.  Firstly, you don't need to write `times(1)`, as this is the default verification mode for Mockito.  It is enough to write `verify(mockedMethodInterceptor).invoke(expectedInvocation);`  Secondly, be aware that the `equals` method will be used to compare `expectedInvocation` to the real invocation that occurs when you run your test.